# Inverted mirror/live duplicate

Tags: scripting, mirror

When mirroring the mirrored side of the object gets inverted (just like a normal mirror). I need the mirrored object to be exactly the same as the other one. Much more like a live duplicate so when I edit the first object the same thing gets applied to the duplicate. How would I do this? If there is no way using the UI then there sure must be a way to do this in a script, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press Alt + D to create an instance (live duplicate as I called it in the question)

Answer (score 1):

Or,  you can apply an array modifier set the offset to what you want  and  then start doing  what you want on the original mesh. After you're  done hit apply